# Can you set the year/month of the HTML date input on initial dropdown?

Tags: html, date

I have a date field which the browser responds to by dropping down a datepicker for the current month. Since I have to have code, here you go:

```
<input type=date name=notimportant />
```

More importantly, here's what it looks like:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is change it so the month and year shows whatever I want WITHOUT setting the value of the input. Basically, I want to control the first/default drop down date information.

This is because I have an app that work in the past or future and it's annoying to have to constantly scroll back or forward months or years to the date/time the user is actually working in.

Comment: Nope you must set the value. But as an aside, unless you *need* to see other potentially conflicting due dates, there is no reason to use a date picker, using either `type="number"` or `type="tel"` + formatting in JS, would be better.

Comment: I want users to be able to see the calendar and navigate rather than having to manually enter a date. It's far easier.

Comment: ... You're wrong? You literally just experienced yourself and now you're trying to find a peacemeal hack (setting the default) to make it somewhat more useable. Having to navigate is a pain in the ass. Compare that to a text field where you just type numbers and have the slashes automatically inserted.

Comment: The *only* reason for a date picker is if you want to simultaneously display potentially conflicting dates (so the users can "pick" around them).

Comment: @marblewraith, Despite your assurances that there's only one possible reason to use  datepicker, my goal here is specifically to let users visually browse dates, not just enter a date. That said, you still CAN manually enter the date in a date field anyway so covered either way. Do you have any tips for solving the problem asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you are trying to do, the easiest solution is to provide an easy way for users to change the date, even across years. The jQuery datepicker is your answer. It contains controls to move easily month to month:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
  $( "#date" ).datepicker();
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like that might be the only solution as the built-in HTML only uses today's date as an "anchor".

Comment: True. But it might also be the best, since your user can go backwards and forwards by years relatively easily. And it’s easier for you to maintain. If this solves your problem, please mark this as the answer.